# Can dx be equal to dy?

Tags: calculus

I am taking baby steps into calculus. While reading "Calculus made easy" by S.Thompson, I came across this confusing statement:

**"Suppose we make $x$ to vary, that is to say, we either alter it or
imagine it to be altered, by adding to it a bit which we call $dx.$ We are
thus causing $x$ to become $ x + dx.$ Then, because $x$ has been altered,
$y$ will have altered also, and will have become $y + dy.$ Here the bit dy
may be in some cases positive, in others negative; and it won’t (except
by a miracle) be the same size as $dx.$"**

What does the last sentence mean? $dx$ cannot be equal to $dy$?

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$, but unless $y=x$ you won't have $dy=dx$ for any increment $dx$.  For example if $y=2x$ then for every increment $dx$ you get $2dy$.

Comment: The last sentence means: In the vast majority of cases $dy$ will be different from $dx$, but in special cases they can be equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $dy=dx\longrightarrow \frac {dy}{dx}=1$ is the derivative of the curve $y=x$.

Comment: $+\text{constant}$

Comment: @GFauxPas What I said is true. Take $k=0$ if you will.

Comment: I was just adding "the other answers". `+1`